# LibSVM training error

Tags: libsvm

I’m using java version of libsvm (regression) for prediction purposes.
After training my data set, the generated model shows the Support Vectors, but no indication on the training error rate. 
I would like to know if it's possible to find the training error of my training set? Is there any function I can call, or a class attribute I can use to find it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a svm_problem from your training-set and call svm_predict(..) on that - then compute the MSE (mean squared error) - but note that [LibSVM performs quite poor on regression datasets compared to neural networks](http://svm-vs-nn.html).