# Compute the training error and test error in libsvm + MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, libsvm

I would like to draw learning curves for a given SVM classifier. Thus, in order to do this, I would like to compute the training, cross-validation and test error, and then plot them while varying some parameter (e.g., number of instances `m`).

How to compute training, cross-validation and test error on `libsvm` when used with MATLAB?

I have seen other answers (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158891/libsvm-training-error)) that suggest solutions for other languages.

Isn't there a compact way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of instances described by:

- a set of features `featureVector`;
- their corresponding `labels` (e.g., either 0 or 1),

if a `model` was previously inferred via `libsvm`, the MSE error can be computed as follows:

```
[predictedLabels, accuracy, ~] = svmpredict(labels, featureVectors, model,'-q');
MSE = accuracy(2);
```

Notice that `predictedLabels` contains the labels that were predicted by the classifier for the given instances.